# Find angle of line which runs perpendicular to a tangent trajectory of a point on 2d cartesian frame

Tags: geometry, coordinate-systems, angle

As below, I am looking to find the variable '$\theta_e$'. Assuming the parameters which are given are the point ($x,y$) , ($L_h$),($d_e$), v, ($\theta_d$), ($x_d,y_d$). I do not have the parameter '$\theta$'.

The only information I have about the problem is that the line '$d_e$' runs perpendicular to a tangent trajectory at ($x_d,y_d$) with an angle '$\theta_e$' .

Is it possible that I can find '$\theta_e$' ? Any idea?

[image]

Comment: Welcome to MSE. For some basic information about writing mathematics at this site see, e.g., [basic help on mathjax notation](https://math.stackexchange.com/help/notation), [mathjax tutorial and quick reference](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5020), [main meta site math tutorial](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/70559), and [equation editing how-to](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1773)

Comment: im totally lost on this hence i had to ask here.

Answer (score 3):

If $Q$ is the common endpoint between segments $L_h$ and $d_e$, then we can compute its coordinates in two ways:
$$
Q=(x+L_h\cos\theta,y+L_h\sin\theta)=(x_d+d_e\sin\theta_d,y_d-d_e\cos\theta_d).
$$
From that we can then compute angle $\theta$ and finally: $\theta_e=\theta_d-\theta$.

[image]

Comment: thx. i will give it a try